# Unable to shutdown Linux laptop

Tags: linux, operating-systems, shutdown, lenovo-laptop, oracle-linux

I have installed oracle Linux on my Lenovo Thinkpad laptop. I am not able to  shut it down. When I issue poweroff command. It is stuck with message/log as

```
[31431.834130] reboot: Power down
```

My system info:

OS:
   Oracle Linux Server release 7.7

Hardware:
         Manufacturer: LENOVO
         Product Name: 20FMS05G01
        Version: ThinkPad T460

Please help.
--Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using poweroff, try using `sudo shutdown -h now`.

This runs all the shutdown scripts, halts the machine and powers it down.

Comment: No Luck with 'sudo shutdown -h now' too